# Implementing facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Hi i am using new sdks of facebook for publishing.Everything is working fine except that i am unable to login from my android app if already facebook is installed means that if **facebook** application is n**ot installed on phone** i can **sucessfully post data** to facebook through my mobile application but if user **has installed the facebook app , i cannot post my data**.

Kindly help me in this stuff..

Sorry for incorrect English..

Comment: Just guessing, have you used keytool to export your key and add it to your facebook app (on developer.facebook.com)?

Comment: Can you please elaborate sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your problem I suggest you look at [this](http://p-xr.com/implementing-facebook-into-your-app-invalid-key-with-keytool/).
The crux of the problem is that the keytool on windows messes up the key hash. 
Do

`"keytool -export ..."` instead of `"keytool -exportcert ...";`

Both generate keys but the second one messes it up.

You can also get the key by putting this in your activity

```
try {
   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.yourcompany.client", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
   for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("Hash Key:", Base64.encode(md.digest()));
   }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer and +1 for help